# Nav-pills abrir para esquerda

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estou seguindo o seguinte código:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  ...
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Porém gostaria que o dropdown abrisse para esquerda.
Tentei a classe `pull-left` porém sem sucesso.

Alguma ajuda ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVIDO**

Adicionei o seguinte estilo à tag `<ul>`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="right: 0; left: auto;">
```